# NetBeans: "The package already exists" error when package.subpackage exists

Tags: java, netbeans

After moving to maven, whole my project glitched and randomly throws `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` for classes. I discovered that once I refactor the package with that class to something else, like `blahblahblah` and then back to original name, the glitch is gone.

I have these packages:

- cz.autoclient.autoclick
- cz.autoclient.autoclick.comvis

I had to refactor `cz.autoclient.autoclick` because of this error:

Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: cz/autoclient/autoclick/ColorPixel

But when I wanted to refactor it back from `blahblah` to `cz.autoclient.autoclick`, netbeans won't let me do that:

Here's a picture. You can see that standalone `cz.autoclient.autoclick` doesn't exist:

[image: image description]

I must say that I'm becoming really angry about this consistent problem and the way my IDE hadnles it. During rage-refactoring I also noticed that netbeans is capable of concurently refactoring files with the result of two names being messed up together. Like `aublahtocliblahck`.

How can I now convince netbeans that to create the original package for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After googling for a while, I discovered quick fix:

1. Enable full tree view for project explorer
   [image: image description]
2. Now, the top level package containing sub-packages will bee seen and you can drag'n'drop the class files from `blahblah` package.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to get classes to the right package:

1. select the classes you want to move
2. right-click
3. refactor →‎ move

Alternatively, simply select the classes and press Ctrl + M.